# JavaScript check if element is outside top viewport

Tags: javascript, viewport

I have a code that works just fine to check if element is outside of bottom viewport, as follows:

```
function posY(elm) {
let test = elm, top = 0;

while(!!test && test.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "body") {
    top += test.offsetTop;
    test = test.offsetParent;
}

return top;
}

function viewPortHeight() {
let de = document.documentElement;

if(!window.innerWidth)
{ return window.innerHeight; }
else if( de && !isNaN(de.clientHeight) )
{ return de.clientHeight; }

return 0;
}

function scrollY() {
if( window.pageYOffset ) { return window.pageYOffset; }
return Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);
}

function checkvisible (elm) {
let vpH = viewPortHeight(), // Viewport Height
    st = scrollY(), // Scroll Top
    y = posY(elm);

return (y > (vpH + st));
}

        if (hasActivity && isHidden) {
            isVisibleCSS = <div className='onscreen'>More activity below ↓</div>;
        } else if (hasActivity && !isHidden) {
            //technically, there's no need for this here, but since I'm paranoid, let's leave it here please.
        }
```

My question is, how can I adapt this code or create a new one similar to this one that identifies when element is outside of top viewport?

Cheers.

Comment: I think you can broadcast your custom events when the element is outside top viewport. Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217465/how-are-custom-broadcast-events-implemented-in-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 2):

For an element to be completely  off the view  top  then the sum of the element's top offset and it's height, like in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/mgeL8ezb/)

```js
var $test = document.getElementById('test'),
  $tOffset = $test.offsetTop,
  $tHeight = $test.clientHeight,
  $winH = window.innerHeight,
  $scrollY;


window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  $scrollY = window.scrollY;
  if ($scrollY > ($tOffset + $tHeight)) {
    console.log('out of the top');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 200px;
  height: 1500px;
}
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, I sincerely appreciate the code, but I was looking for a non-JQuery way of approaching this, sorry. I have tested implementing without JQuery but I think I screwed up along the way because I'm not getting the result I expected. I believe it's the element height, seeing as it never changes when I iterate through the id's...

Comment: The answer is in vanilla - *pure* - javascript, not jquery but I just put the `$` mark in front of the variables names just as naming convention for me